# Can't set increment function in React JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am making React.js aplication. For backend I use Node.js and mysql for database.
I am trying to make simple LIKE. I want that one person can just add 1 like per ad (advertisment) when Click Like button and send that to database then render from database.
I success that with an input tag(which now is commented).
Here is Code:
(Frontend)

```
function Ads() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
  const [adsList, showAdsList] = useState([]);
  const [currLike, setLike] = useState(0);

  const getAds = async () => {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/showAds').then((response) => {
      showAdsList(response.data);
    })
  };
  const addLike = async (id) => {
    await axios.put('http://localhost:3001/update', {
      id: id,
      likes: currLike
    }).then((response) => {
      setLike(...currLike, {
        id: id,
        likes: currLike
      })
      window.location.reload();
    })
  };
  //Shows Ads when I load the page
  useEffect(() => {
    getAds();
  }, []);
  return (
    ///...
///
      <div className="showAds" >
        {adsList.map((val, key) => {
          return <div className="ad" key={key}>
            <h4> {val.content}</h4>
            <h5><a href="">{val.adress}</a></h5>
            <h5>Likes: {val.likes}</h5>
            <div>
              {""}
              {/* <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="2000..."
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setLike(event.target.value );
                }}
              /> */}
              <button type="submit" onClick={() => { addLike(val.id) }} className = "btn btn-success" > LIKE</button>
          </div>
          </div>
        })}
    </div>
    </div >
  )
}
export default Ads;
```

Comment: Dude please, avoid window.location.reload() in React, use a state update  to reset the state, use reload as a last resort, I implore you to read the new documents and we in the community will be there to help you with things you are having difficulty with
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reacting-to-input-with-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should help you:

you don't need to do a **window.location.reload()** either the **currLike** like state

```js
import React from "react";
import JSONDATA from '../MOCK_DATA.json';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import './Components.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Ads() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
  const [adsList, showAdsList] = useState([]);
  

  const getAds = async () => {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/showAds').then((response) => {
      showAdsList(response.data);
    })
  };
  const addLike = async (id, likes) => {
    await axios.put('http://localhost:3001/update', {
      id,
      likes
    }).then((response) => {
    
    const newState = adsList.map(list => {
      if(list.id === id){
      
      return {...list, likes};
      
      }
      
      return list;
    
    })
    showAdsList(newState);
    
    
    })
  };
  const events = [{ text: "Kategorije" }, { text: "Kafići" }, { text: "Klubovi" }, { text: "Restorani" }, { text: "Sport" }, { text: "Kultura" }, { text: "Priroda" }, { text: "Studentska događanja" }, { text: "Privatne zabave" }];
  //Shows Ads when I load the page
  useEffect(() => {
    getAds();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <div className="categories">
            <select>
              {events.map((val, i) => <option key={i}>{val.text}</option>)}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-3">
          <div className="town-filter">
            <select>
              {JSONDATA.map((val, key) => {
                return <option key={key}> {val.town_name}</option>
              })}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <div className="calendar-filter"  >
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-calendar4-week" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM2 2a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1h14V3a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2zm13 3H1v9a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5z" />
              <path d="M11 7.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1zm-3 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1zm-2 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1zm-3 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1z" />
            </svg>
            <label>
              <DatePicker selected={selectedDate}
                onChange={date => setSelectedDate(date)}
                dateFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'
                minDate={new Date()}
                isClearable
              />
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-1">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Filtriraj</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="showAds" >
        {adsList.map((val, key) => {
          return <div className="ad" key={key}>
            <h4> {val.content}</h4>
            <h5><a href=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="#bb2d3b" className="bi bi-geo-alt-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M8 16s6-5.686 6-10A6 6 0 0 0 2 6c0 4.314 6 10 6 10zm0-7a3 3 0 1 1 0-6 3 3 0 0 1 0 6z"></path>
            </svg>{val.adress}</a></h5>
            <h5>Likes: {val.likes}</h5>
            <div>
              {""}
              {/* <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="2000..."
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setLike(event.target.value );
                }}
              /> */}
              <button type="submit" onClick={() => { addLike(val.id, val.likes + 1) }} className = "btn btn-success" > LIKE</button>
          </div>
          </div>
        })}
    </div>
    </div >
  )
}
export default Ads;
```

Comment: @AnaAlilovic marking the answer as helpful and vote up will be nice

Comment: I was immediately try to vote but I have to have 15 reputation to do that, but now I save the answer and accept it. Once again thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to disable button after one click? I am trying with :
 <button type="submit" onClick={() => { addLike(val.id, val.likes + 1);handleClick}} className="btn btn-success" > LIKE</button> and the handle click function is :
const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.target.disabled = true;
    console.log(event);
    console.log('button clicked');
  };
But it doesn't work

Comment: in your onClick pass the param like onClick={(e)=> {addLike(val.id, val.likes + 1);handleClick(e <- here too)}}